# Cambiar el OPTION de un SELECT usando JavaScript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una base de datos con las opciones de los usuarios, y varias de estas opciones se ajustan con selects, y lo que necesito es que cuando se cargue la página, **se muestren seleccionados los valores recuperados** de la base de datos.

He probado con varios códigos como este y no entiendo porque no funciona y tampoco da errores en la consola:

```
$("#selectLang").prop("selectedIndex", 2);

// También he probado con esto:

$("#selectLang").val('2');
```

> **Nota:** El 2, en mi código es `<?php echo $lang_value; ?>`, y desde la
>   consola aparece que se ha imprimido correctamente.

Código HTML del select del ejemplo:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputState">Idioma</label>
  <select id="inputState selectLang" class="form-control" name="lang">
    <option value="1">Español</option>
    <option value="2">English</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Es posible que en el `.prop` se empiecen a contar desde el 0, pero tampoco funcionan cuando el valor es 1.

> **Aclaraciones:** La ID no está duplicada, el código jQuery está al final
>   del código y he probado tanto con comillas como sin comillas. No uso el `selected` porque hay demasiadas opciones y habría que hacer un `if` para cada una.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El id de tu `<select>` tiene un espacio. O bien lo haces así:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id="inputState selectLang"]').val('2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputState">Idioma</label>
  <select id="inputState selectLang" class="form-control" name="lang">
    <option value="1">Español</option>
    <option value="2">English</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

O simplemente le cambias el id:

```
 <select id="selectLang" class="form-control" name="lang">
```

Edit: la [especificación de HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id) no permite espacio en el atributo id, luego yo lo cambiaría.